# Start a-scene only when scene assets loaded [aframe]

Tags: javascript, aframe

I have some videos and audio files in my scene that take some time to load. Would like to only start the scene when all of these elements are loaded, i.e. ready to play. So, basically how can I only show the scene when all the assets are loaded?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A-Frame has an Asset Management System for that. Have a look at the [docs](https://aframe.io/docs/0.7.0/core/asset-management-system.html).

Comment: For some reason, even when I use the timeout attribute, the bigger obj model in my scene (a room) still appears a few seconds behind of the rest of the scene.

Comment: Maybe it's not the _loading_ that takes that long, but the actual _rendering_ of the room?

Comment: Perhaps. The same thing happens with the videos when using a mobile or another computer. In the video's place it shows a gray rectangle instead of the video. That's why I assume they are taking more time to load.

Comment: You should be able to track the loading times with the Chrome debugger. If the objects appear as soon as they are downloaded, it's a loading problem. If there is a pause, it's probably a rendering problem.

Comment: It's hard to tell. Sometimes the videos work, sometimes they don't. It also depends on my internet speed. That's why I think it's a loading issue. Thus my question.